# Use JavaScript to automatically navigate to a set list of pages

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, navigator

I have created a dashboard which displays real time information for the status of each environment.

As this is going to be displayed on a large monitor I would like it to automatically switch between a set list of pages, preferably in a JavaScript array.

eg.

["page1.html", "page2.html", "page3.html", "page4.html", ... ]

When I am on page1, I would like it to load page2 after a couple of minutes. After a couple of minutes on page2 I then want it to load page3 etc...

I understand how to do the actual page switch, but I am having trouble with figuring out how to get the page to use the next entry in the array.

Comment: Do you have the code you would use to switch the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple and convenient method would be, to have or to create an `<iframe>` element (respectively a new `window` instance) and remotely access that document from your parent site.

So let's say we have an `<iframe>`, we access that via Javascript in a way like

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe'),
    pages  = ["page1.html", "page2.html", "page3.html", "page4.html" ];

iframe.src = pages[ 0 ];
```

All you would have left to do is to implement a *Timer-loop* using `setTimeout` or so to iterate through the array entries.

Comment: Iframe would be the simplest way to do this, as it would make it easier for me to control the navigation. Was stuck thinking about changing the whole page. Thanks.

Comment: @UsainBloot it's not impossible to have a complete change of sites with Javascript only. But you would need to pass information around through each and every call of a new site. There are several ways to accomplish that, for instance use the `localStorage` to share data between your pages or directly pass information in the url.